# Using this method what's the probability that the manager will get the right answer?

Tags: probability

There are 2 interns in the analytics team. Each intern gets correct answers to the problems in 14 cases out of 17. To be more confident in the decision making process, the manager has decided to give both interns the same problem: if both of them gets the same answer, the manager will pick that answer, otherwise he will pick the answer randomly. If the manager decides to follow this approach what's the probability that he will get  the right answer?

My attempt:
The probability that the intern will get the right answer is 14/17, and the manager has 50% chance to choose one of the interns.

Probability that both interns get the right answer $= 14/17*14/17 = 196/289$ (it doesn't matter which intern the manager will choose, since they both got the correct answer) 
Probability that interns get different answers, but the manager picks the right one $= 14/17*3/17*1/2 = 42/578$ 
Probability that interns get different answers, but the manager picks the wrong one $= 14/17*3/17*1/2 = 42/578$ 
Probability that both interns get the wrong answer $= 3/17 * 3/17 = 9/289$ (again it doesn't matter which intern he'll choose) 
I think these are all the possible cases, however when I sum up the probabilities I don't get 1, so I think I messed up somewhere...

Answer (score 1):

The probabilities that are supposed to sum to one are the different probabilities of various right/wrong answer combos. That sum is

$$ \frac{196}{289} + \frac{42}{289} + \frac{42}{289} + \frac{9}{289} = 1.$$

The probability you get from summing the values

$$ \frac{196}{289} + \frac{42}{578} + \frac{42}{578} = \frac{238}{289} $$

is the probability that the manager gets the right answer by asking the interns for information.